# PHP search engine redirects to another page

Tags: php, search, redirect

I have a personal movie database website.
I created a search engine where users can use one or more search criteria (i.e. movie length, title, genre, actors and so on...)

The search engine is working great but I would like to add a "Pick a random movie" feature so the script will pick a single title when we don't know what to watch.

Right now my search engine is called "search.php" and the form is pointing to "search-go.php".  The search results are listed in a table.  Now I would like to validate if the user checked the box "Random movie" in search-go.php, if it's the case, it would pick a random movie ID and then display the movie description (details.php) instead of showing the results table.

I don't know if i'm clear enough, let's simplify that:

search.php -> (user input search criteria) -> search-go.php lists the results in a table

search.php -> (user input search criteria AND checks "random movie" box) -> search-go.php runs a script to pick a random movie ID -> details.php is displaying the selected movie details.

Is it possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, as described below. Where did you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header("Location: details.php?id=$id");
```

BTW,

> my search engine is called "search.php" and the form is pointing to "search-go.php".

This is wrong. It have to be the same `"search.php"`

Comment: According to what I've read, "header" will only load first thing in the script.  That will not let the page run the script to find the random id, right?

Comment: Dunno what you read but it does the very thing that was asked.

Comment: Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. Source:  PHP.net

Comment: "load first thing in the script" and "output is sent" are quite different matters? I don't quite understand the first sentence though

Comment: That make sense, I thought the header could only be on the first line of the script.  I'll try that, thanks!  By the way, why do you say that I am wrong with search-go.php?

Comment: it is quite basic usability issue. You will find that out as soon as you start using your site yourself.

Comment: I've used the site for years and I didn't see any problem dealing with "search.php" and "search-go.php"...  But anyhow, the "header" trick did work thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible.

Add a checbox in search.php, look if the checkbox has been checked in search-go.php and if so,  do a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM movies ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1
```

and then display the result in details.php.

Comment: That sounds great, but my concern is not the actual query, it's more about how I make the page automatically redirects to details.php?id=xx after the query...

Comment: Let's say you do your query and you fetch the content in $data. A simple header("Location: details.php?id=".$data['movieID']); would be fine.